# Images turned 90 degrees counterclockwise

Tags: graphics, xetex, texshop

Using XeLaTeX under TeXShop 4.52 on MacOS 10.13.6, the following error occurs. The command `\includegraphics[width=w]{myPic.jpg}` (with an appropriate value of w) almost always displays myPic correctly, both landscape and portrait formats. But SOMETIMES portrait-format images are turned counterclockwise by 90 degrees. Turning the original jpg does not help, even if turned clockwise by 90 degrees.

What does seem to help in one example: converting the original unprocessed jpg (4.2 MB) to eps (72.8 MB) and then to jpg (1.8 MB) with
`convert myPic.eps -quality 100 myPic.jpg`.
Both eps and new jpg display correctly under XeLaTeX.

But it does not help me. This is part of a large book project (currently 40 GB in pdf, and growing) and 70 MB per image is too much. On the other hand, the twice-converted jpg loses quality compared to the original, and it would be tiresome to do these conversions for a hundred images.

Annoying: some of the original jpg's (from a Panasonic Lumix DMC-FT20 and a Nikon D-800) display correctly, others do not. Go figure!

findelmundo

Comment: are you sure it isnt your pdf viewer they often set to "auto rotate"

Comment: Could this be a problem caused by EXIF data (orientation flag)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am viewing the pdf within TeXShop. Under preview and under Acrobat Pro, images are still turned.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: It might be the EXIF data. When preview shows the correct orientation, the "General" info says "Orientation: 6 (Rotated 90° CCW)", and the latexed image is indeed rotated by 90 degrees ccw. But when I turn the image in preview in any of the four 90-degree turns, it shows the angle correctly in info (including "Orientation: 1 (Normal)" in one position), but the latexed image is still rotated by 90 degrees ccw, no matter how I turned the image in preview.

Comment: you can always turn it back by  adding `,angle=-90` to the `\includegraphics options.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle angle=-90 solved the problem for single images. But when I put two images side by side (with enough space on the page), then latex puts them diagonally one above the other. Not good. The original image has the info "Orientation: 6 (Rotated 90° CCW)". I changed the image in preview, say increasing Sharpness by a tiny bit (or any other minor change, as far as I can tell). Then by miracle I get the correct "Orientation: 1 (Normal)". Without rotating the image. But rotating several times does not have such an effect. Some quirk on downloading the (many) images?

Comment: impossible to guess with no example. But if you have fixed your images in an image editor perhaps the problem is solved? `\includegraphics` has no positioning logic at all tex just sees it as a big rectangular letter and it takes part in normal paragraph line breaking. Rotating the image pobviously changes the dimensions of the rectangle which may indirectly affect its position.